Internal Compiler Error: Segmentation Fault
I am getting the following error every time I try to build or make a package:
In file included from /usr/include/gz/math7/gz/math/AxisAlignedBox.hh:25,
                 from /home/jjayalekshmi/gz-rendering-cpy/include/gz/rendering/Visual.hh:21,
                 from /home/jjayalekshmi/gz-rendering-cpy/src/Visual.cc:18:
/usr/include/gz/math7/gz/math/MassMatrix3.hh: In member function ‘gz::math::v7::Vector3<T> gz::math::v7::MassMatrix3<T>::PrincipalMoments(T) const’:
/usr/include/gz/math7/gz/math/MassMatrix3.hh:498:20: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
  498 |         T p = std::pow(b, 2) - 3*c;
      |                    ^~~
0x78952a04251f ???
    ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
0x78952a029d8f __libc_start_call_main
    ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
0x78952a029e3f __libc_start_main_impl
    ../csu/libc-start.c:392
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-rendering8.dir/build.make:930: src/CMakeFiles/gz-rendering8.dir/Visual.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1626: src/CMakeFiles/gz-rendering8.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2

I ran MemTest for 17 hours and it ran without errors. I have also under-clocked the CPU to ensure the system is not overheating.
I have downgraded to gcc version 11.4.0
PC build details:
I am using the MSI MAG Z790 Tomahawk motherboard, TeamGroup T-Force Vulcan 32GB (2x16GB) RAM, Intel Core i9-14900K 24 cores 14th Gen CPU and a Tesla P100 GPU.
What can I do next to try and fix this issue?
P.S.: This is a new system and these programs were running without any issues at the time. I started facing these issues after not using the system for a week and the computer for left on during this period. The system was hanging when I came back. I have tried reinstalling the OS. I have also tried running it on a single RAM. And the system still hangs every now and then.

You should search the GCC bug tracker to see if this ICE was previously reported and if so, if there's a workaround in the issue comments.  Or, you can try upgrading your GCC to a newer version.

I have upgraded my GCC version, I am currently using
gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0

Hm.  Based on the path in your question above it seems like you're using GCC 11.  But maybe I'm misinterpreting?  Examine the compiler line printed by make (which you unfortunately don't show us in your question) then run <compiler> -v to see what version you get.

An ICE indicates a bug in the compiler, or at least in your build of it.  At minimum, if a flaw in the code or environment is detected as erroneous, then it is buggy for the compiler to report that as an ICE.  This is why the error message specifically asks you to "Please submit a full bug report".  More often than not, however, an ICE reflects a deeper problem than mis-classifying an error.  Your issue is very unlikely to be a hardware problem.

gcc -v command gives the following output:
gcc version 12.3.0 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

This is a new system and these programs were running without any issues at the time. I started facing these issues after not using the system for a week and the computer for left on during this period. The system was hanging when I came back. I have tried reinstalling the OS. I have also tried running it on a single RAM. And the system hangs every now and then.

Do you get the exact same error message, on the same line, every time you compile the same source code?  If so, compiler bug; file a bug report.  If not, probably hardware failure, and you need to go to http://superuser.com instead.  The fact that your system hangs unpredictably is a separate issue, but it's off topic for Stack Overflow too.

No, the error is not always on the same line. During the first build it goes up to maybe 12 to 15% and shows this error and rebuilding it again continues the build from where it previously stopped.

This was an issue with intel core i9 gen 13/14 cpu. The issue was solved after updating the bios
